# End of line converter

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, console

I recently wrote a python script to convert multiple files EOL's from `Unix` to `DOS` and vice versa.

I am looking for tips to improve my code or if there is a better way of doing something that I have missed.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys

def main():
    command, *filenames = sys.argv[1:]
    valid_commands = ['-d', '-u']
    sys.tracebacklimit = None

    if not command in valid_commands:
        error = """'{command}'
        Provide the following arguments -u|d file [file2] [file3] ...
        flags:
            -u : converts DOS to UNIX
            -d : converts UNIX to DOS
        example command:
            ./eol -u foo.py bar.py""".format(command=command)

        raise ValueError(error)
        sys.exit(1)

    if filenames:
        convert(filenames, command)
    else:
        print("> no files to convert")

def convert(files, command):
    for file in files:
        text = open(file, 'r').read()

        with open(file, 'w') as current:
            if command == '-u':
                format = 'UNIX'
                current.write(text.replace('\r\n', '\n'))
            elif command == '-d':
                format = 'DOS'
                current.write(text.replace('\n', '\r\n'))

        print("> converting file {filename} to {format} ...".format(
              filename=file, format=format))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of small observations:

1. `sys.exit(1)` will never be reached so you can remove it. Apparently, you don't want to show, to whoever will be using your script, the traceback though that's not what I'd recommend. It's nice to know why and how the program failed (and even if you don't want a traceback, you can always create your own custom exception class):

   ```
   class MyCustomException(Exception):
       pass
   ```

   Which you can call like:

   ```
   if bla_bla:
       raise MyCustomException('my message here')
   ```
2. `format = 'UNIX'` and `format = 'DOS'`: they doesn't seem to be used anywhere else in the code so you can remove them.
3. Change `if not command in valid_commands:` to `if command not in valid_commands:`
4. Use two blank lines between your functions
5. Use [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) module to handle command line arguments
6. This: `text = open(file, 'r').read()` will load the whole file in memory which might be bad if you're applying your function on very large file. I'd recommend you process one line at a time, or at least call `f.read(size)`. From the docs:

   > To read a file’s contents, call `f.read(size)`, which reads some
   >   quantity of data and returns it as a string (in text mode) or bytes
   >   object (in binary mode). `size` is an optional numeric argument. When
   >   `size` is omitted or negative, the entire contents of the file will be
   >   read and returned; it’s your problem if the file is twice as large as
   >   your machine’s memory. Otherwise, at most size bytes are read and
   >   returned.

Comment: great points, although i'm not sure if i'm understanding 2. correctly. I use the format variable at the end of the for loop which defines what the initial command was. If I get rid of them then `print("> converting file {filename} to {format} ...".format(
              filename=file, format=format))` would break.

Answer (score 3):

The code in the post does not work, because the files are opened in [text mode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#text-i-o), and in text mode Python 3 translates newlines by default. To quote the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper):

> *newline* controls how line endings are handled. It can be `None`, `''`, `'\n'`, `'\r'`, and `'\r\n'`. It works as follows:
>
> - When reading input from the stream, if *newline* is `None`, universal newlines mode is enabled. Lines in the input can end in `'\n'`, `'\r'`, or `'\r\n'`, and these are translated into `'\n'` before being returned to the caller. If it is `''`, universal newlines mode is enabled, but line endings are returned to the caller untranslated. If it has any of the other legal values, input lines are only terminated by the given string, and the line ending is returned to the caller untranslated.
> - When writing output to the stream, if *newline* is `None`, any `'\n'` characters written are translated to the system default line separator, `os.linesep`. If *newline* is `''` or `'\n'`, no translation takes place. If *newline* is any of the other legal values, any `'\n'` characters written are translated to the given string.

This means that the code in the post never gets to see the original line endings and so it does not behave as intended when run on Windows. (This makes me suspect that it has not been tested in all four configurations: Unix → DOS on Unix; DOS → Unix on Unix; Unix → DOS on Windows; DOS → Unix on Windows.)

In order to operate on the original line endings, you could open the file in [binary mode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#binary-i-o) (both for reading and writing), or open it in text mode but set `newline=''` so that newlines are not translated.

Comment: Great point! I read up on binary mode but was not sure what the intended use for it was. Thank you for clarifying.